# What is a node in TICKscript?

Tags: kapacitor

I'm trying learn TICKscript, but official documentation is messy.

I understand part about variable declaration and expressions in it. But then there are 'nodes'. What's they are?

UPD: I even found their EBNF: https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/reference/spec/, and there is no node definition in it.

What is a node in TICKscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no description of node in syntax of TICKScript, because that is not syntactic concept, but semantic. Node is approximately `Function { Chain }` in EBNF.

Here is description of nodes from documentation: https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/nodes/

> Nodes represent process invocation units that either take data as a
>   batch or a point-by-point stream, and then alter the data, store the
>   data, or trigger some other activity based on changes in the data
>   (e.g., an alert).

You could see visualization of nodes, when you run `kapacitor show <your_task_name>`, and run DOT section of output through `dot` command. You will get something like:

[image: Graph representation of TICKScript]

On that picture nodes of graph will correspond to nodes of your TICKscript.

Comment: I tried to feed a simplest TICKscipt (which is `0`) to kapacitor, but it rejects it as `invalid task type: invalid`. What is a minimal requirements for tickscript to be accepted by kapacitor? (I want some kind of minimal 'hello world' example).

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin I guess even minimal TICKscript requires some input and output. Valid task types are probably batch and stream. Here are some "hello world"-like examples:
https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/tick/introduction/#basic-examples

Comment: Thank you, I'll play around this. (Keywords for me here are 'task types'). I want to construct something simpler than actual working kapacitor alert, just to learn TICKscript as a normal programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @Bunyk, I was able to construct a minimal TICKscript to be accepted by kapacitor.

```
dbrp "a"."b"
stream|from()
```